# Problems with conditioning a column's value from another column's RANGE

Tags: r

I assume that this was asked already, but I was searching a lot and I haven't found any solution yet.
I do have the following `data.frame`

```
date     OCC2010          
 1992-1    8460               
 1992-1    7390               
 1992-1    9999               
 1992-2    244                
 1992-2    2349               
 1992-2    0592
```

What I wanna do is actually pretty simple. I would like to allocate the value 3 to column `SKILLOCC`, if a row in column OCC2010 is within range of certain numbers, e.g. `8460:9999`, as specified in the following table.

```
date     OCC2010          SKILLOCC
 1992-1    8460               4
 1992-1    7390               0
 1992-1    9999               4
 1992-2    244                0
 1992-2    2349               0
 1992-2    0592               0
```

```
df$SKILLEDOCC <- 0
df[df$OCC2010 == 8460:9999,]
df[df$OCC2010 == 8460:9999,]$SKILLEDOCC <- "3"
```

I used that code already for one value or a value < x and it worked. If I try it with a range, the error

`> is not a multiple of the length of the connecting object`
occurs. Does anyone have an idea how to fix that? Or is there another smarter way?

Many thanks in advance

Xx
Freddy

Answer (score 1):

It would be `%in%` as `==` is elementwise comparison and works only in two cases - 1) when both the lengths are the same, 2) when the rhs length is 1 so that it recycles.

```
df$SKILLEDOCC[df$OCC2010 %in% 8460:9999] <- 3
```

Also, it is better to do the assignment on a `vector` (`df$SKILLEDOC`), instead of the `data.frame` indexing

Or as @thelatemail suggested a comparison operation may be more efficient

```
df$SKILLEDOCC[df$OCC2010 >= 8460 & df$OCC2010 <= 9999] <- 3
```

Comment: If it's a range of numbers, there's no need to generate the (potentially very large) `low:high` sequence, e.g.: - `df$SKILLEDOCC[df$OCC2010 >= 8460 & df$OCC2010 <= 9999] <- 3`

Comment: @thelatemail yes, you are right.  I was about to update that. thanks